# How to install gitversion on Ubuntu 18.04.4?

Tags: software-installation, git

I am trying to install [gitversion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) in our build server in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-1030-aws x86_64). The documentation has very little instruction. I found tar.gz file in github ([here](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/releases)) upon uncompressing using following command I only got a single file named "gitversion".

```
wget https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/releases/download/5.3.7/gitversion-ubuntu.18.04-x64-5.3.7.tar.gz
tar -xvf gitversion-ubuntu.18.04-x64-5.3.7.tar.gz
```

I am completely lost after that. Judging by the lack of instruction in documentation, I am guessing this should be simple or obvious. May be the problem is I am newbie.

I also looked [here](https://www.river.red/install-gitversion-ubuntu-16-04/). but this instruction is using a zip file that is not available for latest release.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: I came across that question. The answers there says to call  "./configure". I think the answer assumes that uncompressing the tar.gz file gives a file named "configure" In my case there is only one file called "gitversion". so calling ./configure gives me this message.  

-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you read the install instructions that are linked to in the README?

Comment: @user535733 Not sure what you are pointing to. I do not see any instruction in README. Could you share a link perhaps?

Comment: Looks like the documentation you are referring just says install mono-complete. and run mono gitversion.exe The problem is I do not get exe file when I uncompress the tar.gz file. So I am still lost. 

I have opened an issue in github. Hopefully I will get some guidance from there. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, you're right: If the file you need isn't in the tarball, not much Ubuntu can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is an old question, but if you came to the question more recently the correct answer is now in the [official docs](https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/cli/installation)

[image: Offical Docs]

And here is my version of using it:

```
echo Download the installer script
export DOTNET_INSTALL_SCRIPT=/tmp/dotnet-install.sh
wget https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/scripts/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O $DOTNET_INSTALL_SCRIPT
chmod --verbose u+x $DOTNET_INSTALL_SCRIPT

echo Run the installer script for the GA release of .net 7.0
$DOTNET_INSTALL_SCRIPT --quality GA --channel 7.0 

echo set up the paths
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/.dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT:$DOTNET_ROOT/tools

echo install and run gitversion
dotnet tool install --global GitVersion.Tool
dotnet-gitversion /updateprojectfiles
```

[image: running the script]

Answer (score 4):

Yea. The GitVersion doc on installation is somewhat blur for linux distros. Well, answering your question above i think I figured it out. Move the gitversion binary generated after the `tar -xvf gitversion-ubuntu.18.04-x64-5.3.7.tar.gz` to /usr/local/bin. See complete installation steps below:

```bsh
wget https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/releases/download/5.3.7/gitversion-ubuntu.18.04-x64-5.3.7.tar.gz
tar -xvf gitversion-ubuntu.18.04-x64-5.3.7.tar.gz
sudo mv gitversion /usr/local/bin
```

Also the gitversion tool works only on git initialized directory. Happy semantic versioning!!!

Comment: Thank you @knoxknot.  You gave me some valuable insights into coming up with my answer